# Why does running "devtools::check()" cause a custom function to be recognised by R- why doesn't my function get recognised before this step?

Tags: r, devtools

I work for an academic project called "DataSHIELD" ( https://www.datashield.ac.uk ), and I am involved in the development and testing of new functions for them. One of the new functions is called "`ds.glmPredict`" which is a customised version of the native R "`predict.glm()`" function, but with changes such that no non-disclosive statistics are brought back to the data analyst (this is the general goal of the whole DataSHIELD project).

This function code is included in a github project and branch, which I pull into an RStudio project so that everything is placed in the right directory.

But then if I, say, try to load the help for this specific function "`ds.glmPredict`";

```
> ?ds.glmPredict()
Error in .helpForCall(topicExpr, parent.frame()) : 
  no methods for ‘ds.glmPredict’ and no documentation for it as a function
```

Yet if I then run `devtools::check()` this works through something behind the scenes in R (excuse my ignorance of devtools, I have never come across a good source that explains to me what devtools package is or does in simple language) and after it has finished, I can run `?ds.glmPredict()` and it will produce the help console information that I wanted in the first place:

```
> ?ds.glmPredict()
Rendering development documentation for 'ds.glmPredict'
```

Is it some problem with DataSHIELD's infrastructure that causes particular functions to be unrecognised by R upon first launching the program, or is it likely to be something else entirely?

Comment: Your workflow seems to lack the crucial step of building the package. `devtools::check` builds the package (including the documentation) before running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

`devtools::document` will do the trick. `R` can't find the help files because you only pulled the function code without the `.Rd` files that are in `package root\man`, that why it throws the error. `devtools::check` automatically builds and checks a the package and in the building process it calls `devtools::document` which is just a wrapper for `roxygen2::roxygenize` that does the heavy lifting in transforming the special comments into an `.Rd` file.